# How to compare the needed data by selecting check box and to show in list view

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have two check boxes. `1. filter by data, 2. Show pending.`. Below that I am populating some data from database in list view. What I need is, if I press `filter by data` check box, then my list view should reload and show the data from data format. Means that the data which is added first in the database should show first in list view.

In my database I have one parameter called `status`, which will show the status `pending or ordered`. So, if I press `show pending` check box, then the records having pending status, should populate in my list view. Here is my code :

```
<div class="row" >

    <div class="col col-50" style="border-right: 1px #ccc solid;">
        <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 8px;"> <span class="assertive" style="margin: 0px;">Show pending</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-50">
        <input type="checkbox" style="margin: 8px;"> <span class="assertive" style="margin: 0px;">sort by date</span>
    </div>

       </div>
<ion-list>
            <ion-item class="item-icon-right clsOrders" ng-repeat="mydash in MyOrders" ng-click="ShowDetails(mydash)">
                <div class="row" >
                    <div class="col col-20 clsOrderDateMonth">
                        <span class="clsOrderDate">{{mydash.dateAdded}}</span>
                        <div class="spacer" style="height: 5px;"></div>
                        <span class="assertive clsOrderMonth">{{mydash.monthAdded}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-50">
                        <span class="balanced clsOrderDetailNumber">{{mydash.customerName}}</span>
                        <div class="spacer" style="height: 10px;"></div>
                        <div class="clsStatusCount row cls0Padding">
                            <div class="col col-50 cls0Padding">
                                Item:&nbsp;<span class="assertive">{{mydash.productCount}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-40 cls0Padding">
                                <span class="balanced clsMakeContentRight">{{mydash.orderStatus}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-20 cls0Padding">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-25 ">
                        <div class="spacer" style="height: 5px;"></div>
                        <div class="col col-40 cls0Padding" style="margin-top: 26px;font-size: 11px;">
                                Amount:&nbsp;<span class="assertive">{{mydash.orderTotalAmount}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
            </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

**For UI:**
I think you have to associate an action function for checkbox change event.

If you use, `<ion-checkbox>` you have `ionChange` event to execute necessary data processing logic, like this:

`<ion-checkbox (ionChange)="processData(parameters)">
 </ion-checkbox>`

Check out the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/) and [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-use-a-checkbox-in-a-clickable-list/54416) issue on ionic forum.

Also, check if `(click)="processData(parameters)"` works. Not tested this though.

In the list below, UI should be simple enough by using `ngFor` and `ngIf`.

**Script**

Now, the data you are supposed show in list has to be manipulated in this `processData(parameters)` method.

**Note:** But, looking at your use case, I am not sure you are using the correct design. Maintaining status of pending/ordered for one device is fine. But data will get invalid for multiple devices, as different devices' status for what data has loaded and what data is pending will vary. Need more help here understanding the exact use case though.